# Python random.choice() function - how to never have two choices in a row or close to one another

Tags: python, random, module

Let's say I have

```
mychoice = random.choice(['this is random response 1','this is random response 2', 
'this is random response 3', 'and 4', 'and so on'])
```

How can I avoid having the same choice being repeated more than once in a row?  Or how can I can I set a condition to make a particular choice only appear after a certain number of other choices have been chosen?  Or is there a module better suited to my needs in this regard?

Comment: Choosing by any rule is the exact opposite of choosing randomly.

Comment: Are you trying to get random selections without replacement? In that case, you can just remove the values from the list as they come up

Answer (score 8):

the simplest solution would probably be to construct a `usedQueue` of length `k` (where k is the number of selections before a choice is allowed to repeat.)  When you select a choice, remove it from your original list and place it in `usedQueue`.  Then, if `usedQueue.length > k`, pop one back onto your array.

As already stated, this significantly reduces the randomness of your algorithm.  That said, it does have practical uses (take a look at iTunes.)

Answer (score 2):

Example implementation ensuring a minimum distance between two occurrences of the same item:

```
def choice_gen(choices, min_dist):
    last_choices = collections.deque(maxlen=min_dist)
    choices = set(choices)
    while 1:
        c = random.choice(list(choices - set(last_choices)))
        last_choices.append(c)
        yield c
```

Answer (score 0):

This routine selects and prints random choices from mylist without replacement, until all choices have been exhausted.

```
index = range(len(mylist))
while len(index) > 0:
    i = random.choice(index)
    print mylist[i]
    index.pop(i)
```

Comment: This does not do what you intended it to do... [Pop does not remove that value](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists); it removes that index... I think you meant to write "remove" which has the (non-obvious) downside that it runs in O(N) worst-case.