# Python word game issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was looking at a python tutorial on how to create hangman recently. I tried it out but it had some issues with the source code, so I've been trying to write similar code that works well. I've only recently run into an issue. Basically, whenever you guess the last letter in the 'secret' string, it doesn't replace the blank with the letter. I want to know why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Here's the code

```
import random
words = '''aardvark baboon calf camel deer dingo alligator ant jackal iguana 
falcon flamingo macaw manatee marmoset flee emu narwhal leopord ocelot 
lemming opossum dog dolphin dove beaver bison wallaby rabbit salamander 
seagull sheep skunk tiget tortoise unicorn dragon zombie'''.split()

def randomWord(wordList):
    wIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wIndex]

def displayGame(wrong, right, secret):
    print('Wrong Guesses:', end=' ')
    for letter in wrong:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secret)

    for i in range(0, len(secret) - 1):
        if secret[i] in right:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secret[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(guessed):
    while True:
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter.')
        elif guess in guessed:
            print('You have already guessed that letter.')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please print a letter.')
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    print('Would you like to play again? (yes or no)', end=' ')
    while True:
        keepGoing = input()
        if keepGoing == 'yes':
            return True
        elif keepGoing == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print('Yes or no please.')



print('Guessing Game!')
print()
wrong = ''
right = ''
secret = randomWord(words)
gameOver = False
while True:
    while gameOver == False:
        displayGame(wrong, right, secret)

        guess = getGuess(wrong + right)

        if guess in secret:
            right += guess

            foundAll = True
            for i in range(0, len(secret) - 1):
                if secret[i] not in right:
                    foundAll = False
                    break

            if foundAll:
                print('Congratulations! You won! The word was ' + secret)
                gameOver = True
                break

        else:
            wrong += guess

            if len(wrong) > 7:
                print('You ran out of guesses! Game over! The word was ' + secret)
                gameOver = True
                break

    keepGoing = playAgain()
    if keepGoing:
        wrong = ''
        right = ''
        secret = randomWord(words)
        gameOver = False
    else:
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
```

and here's the broken output

```
Would you like to play again? (yes or no) yes
Wrong Guesses: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ 
a
Wrong Guesses: 
_ _ a _ _ _ 
m
Wrong Guesses: m 
_ _ a _ _ _ 
l
Wrong Guesses: m l 
_ _ a _ _ _ 
c
Wrong Guesses: m l c 
_ _ a _ _ _ 
e
Wrong Guesses: m l c 
_ e a _ e _ 
r
Wrong Guesses: m l c 
_ e a _ e _ 
d
Wrong Guesses: m l c d 
_ e a _ e _ 
b
Wrong Guesses: m l c d 
b e a _ e _ 
v
Congratulations! You won! The word was beaver
```

Comment: Can't understand. What was your expected output in your case?

Comment: Instead of picking a random index, you can use ```random.choice```.  See this Stack Overflow question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157967/python-random-choice-function-how-to-never-have-two-choices-in-a-row-or-clos

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in

`for i in range(0, len(secret) - 1)`

range by default excludes the last value, and you are subtracting `1` from this